# Como seleccionar de un grupo si uno tiene un atributo especifico

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

¡Hola de nuevo! tengo el siguiente codigo, es cortito y sencillo (solo un select):

"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE grupo = '$grupo'";

Y la base de datos es esto:

la de usuarios.

- id
- username
- grupo
- exclusivo

la de grupos.

- id
- nombre
- exclusivo (0, 1)

Esos son los datos necesarios, basicamente, al hacer el select, tomo a todos los usuarios que sean del grupo, por ejemplo, "grupo 1", entonces toma todos los datos de estos y los incorpora a un perfil que dice los datos del grupo. Vamos, una perfil de grupo.
Entonces, este perfil tiene una seccion que diria el "nivel" del grupo, este nivel equivale a "exclusivo" en la tabla, si exclusivo = 0, entonces es un usuario o grupo "gratuito", si exclusivo = 1, entonces es un usuario o grupo "exclusivo", los atributos "exclusivo" de las 2 tablas "usuarios" y "grupos" son iguales, si exclusivo en grupo es 0, es lo mismo que si en usuarios el atributo fuera 0, yo tengo algo asi:

Grupo: usuario 1 (gratuito), usuario 2 (gratuito), usuario 3 (exclusivo), usuario 4 (gratuito).

Estos usuarios tienen el atributo "exclusivo" en "0", menos el usuario 3, que lo tiene en "1", basicamente, quiero hacer que, si uno de los usuarios pertenecientes a este grupo, es exclusivo, entonces el grupo al que pertenece se vuelva exclusivo tambien. (como un if, si exclusivo de uno de los usuarios = 1, entonces el grupo tambien = 1, sino, el grupo es = 0.

Comment: Hola Silvia, te invito a leer [ask]. La verdad es un poco confusa tu pregunta. Se entiende que `usuarios` y `grupos` son entidades diferentes. ¿A qué te refieres con: *si un usuario de una tabla tiene un atributo "1" también cambie el atributo de un grupo a "1"*? Puedo suponer que la relación `usuarios` a `grupos` es n:1, por lo tanto si en un grupo hay cierta cantidad de usuarios con atributo 1 y el resto con atributo 0 ¿que valor se cambia en grupo? No tiene sentido o simplemente no entiendo tu lógica. ¿Crees que podrías crear un [mcve]? Saludos

Comment: espera, ya edito la pregunta

Comment: ¿El campo `grupo` de la tabla `usuarios` es una `restricción`? Es decir, ¿el campo `grupo` es una `Foreign Key` de la `Primary Key` de la tabla `grupos`? si es así por convención deberias llamarlo `grupo_id` o `id_grupo`.

Comment: Por otro lado si deseas sólo los usuarios de un grupo específico que además tengan un atributo específico, entonces lo que buscas es usar el operador `AND`, de tal forma que la consulta traiga los resultados que cumplan ambas condiciones pasadas a la sentencia `WHERE`. Por ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE grupo='$grupo' AND exclusivo='$exclusivo'`, siendo `$exclusivo` un valor 1 o 0, de acuerdo a lo que estés filtrando. Saludos

Comment: El campo grupo no es unico, ni PK, ni FK, es simplemente otro dato, puede repetirse y demas, ya que es la mejor manera para relacionar usuarios con grupos en mi opinion.

Comment: En cuanto al SELECT, creo que me diste una idea, porque lo que dices no funcionaria, ya que solo seleccionaria a los usuarios que sean exclusivos o gratuitos, pero no a los 2 juntos, yo lo que quiero es seleccionar a todos los usuarios. Pero en cuanto a tu idea, me refiero a que creo que podria hacer un segundo select, que busque algo como "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE grupo = '$grupo' AND exclusivo = '$exclusivo', entonces hago un num rows, que seria en plan: Si num rows >= 1, y hago que el grupo cambie a "exclusivo", sino, seria "gratuito", esto funciona no? crees que hay una mejor manera?

Comment: Ahora me enredas más, la verdad que no comprendo tu lógica. Un usuario pertenece o se relaciona con un grupo, luego este usuario puede tener exclusividad o no. ¿De qué manera esa exclusividad se relaciona con el grupo al que pertenece? Estás creando una doble relación, y la misma es ambigua. ¿Qué pasa si luego otro usuario se une al mismo grupo (siendo este usuario con exclusividad 0)? ¿Se vuelve a cambiar el valor en el grupo? ¿Y el usuario que ya era exclusivo (valor 1), cambia ahora su valor? Disculpa si lo entiendo mal, pero es que no le veo sentido. Saludos

Comment: Lo siento, acabo de lograrlo gracias a tu idea, acabo de editar la respuesta en caso de que alguien tenga la misma duda, gracias :D!

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, soy terrible explicandome, hago lo posible jasja, pero no importa, lo importante es que resolviste mi problema!

Comment: Silvia, coloca la respuesta en el área de respuestas, es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: Oh, ok, perdon, pense que seria raro poner mi propia respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al margen de que funcione la solucion propuesta, en realidad esta mal la logica...

Asumiendo que los usuarios "exclusivos" son de pago, entonces se pueden unir a un grupo existente, sin que el grupo se deba ver afectado por su "exclusividad"...

Me explico, un usuario "exclusivo" puede crear un grupo, por lo que el grupo sera "exclusivo" (pero no siempre los usuarios desean esta "exclusividad") un usuario no "exclusivo" puede crear un grupo, por lo que este grupo sera "gratuito"...

Entonces, tomando lo anterior en consideracion, tienes mas de dos opciones:

```
Usuario "Exclusivo" crea grupo "Exclusivo"
Usuario "Exclusivo" se une a un grupo "Abierto"
Usuario "Gratuito" crea grupo "Gratuito"
Usuario "Gratuito" se une a grupo "Gratuito"
```

Desde mi humilde punto de vista, los usuarios de paga normalmente pueden elegir si sus publicaciones (o grupos) son "abiertos" o "exclusivos" y tambien, deberian de poder elegir si invitan a un usuario "exclusivo" o "abierto" (a fin de cuentas es su contenido, o no?) y esto agregaria mas opciones de las que estas manejando, por ejemplo "Invitado" que seria un usuario"gratuito" invitado por un "exclusivo" a un grupo "exclusivo"

Tu logica tiene una falla catastrofica, en el caso de que un "gratuito" tenga un grupo y se le una un "exclusivo" el grupo se convertira en "exclusivo" por lo que el "gratuito" ya no tendra acceso a su propio contenido.

Espero que esto sirva de ayuda.

Comment: No no, es buena recomendacion, pero el sistema que tengo se basa en que si un usuario es exclusivo, no importa si creo o no el grupo, el grupo tambien es exclusivo

Comment: No es que los usuarios gratuitos tengan acceso al contenido o no, te explico, si un grupo es exclusivo, puede inscribirse a eventos exclusivos, aunque solo haya uno solo, los permisos exclusivos no los tienen los usuarios, sino que los tienen los grupos, el sistema de "exclusividad" de usuarios es para facilitar la administracion

Comment: Pero tu respuesta es buena igual, le doy un voto, ya que me dio una idea nueva para mi sitio ¡Saludos!

Comment: gracias por el voto, sin embargo (para mi) sigue sin tener sentido la logica, imaginate que solo por el hecho de que tu pagas por un contenido, todos los demas (incluyendo a los que ya tenian acceso) ahora deben pagar por el... OjO: es solo una apreciacion personal.

Comment: Si si, lo se, tiene sentido lo que dices, pero no sabes como funciona mi pagina, creeme que tiene que ser asi xdxdxd, cualqueir cosa lo cambio. Igual, te recomiendo evitar dar "recomendaciones personales" sin que el otro te lo haya pedido, en este sitio muchas veces pueden hasta eliminarte la cuenta por hacer eso, ya que no es algo que un usuario haya pedido. Igual a mi no me molesto, yo en caso de que te encuentres con alguien menos comprensivo que yo jasjas

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de lograr lo que queria al hacer un segundo SELECT, que busca a los usuarios que tengan el nombre del grupo que se busca y "exclusivo" en "1", luego hice un num rows de esto y, si num rows era >= 1, entonces el grupo se volveria "exclusivo", sino, si es == 0, entonces se vuelve "gratuito".
Les doy mi codigo por si alguno tiene la misma pregunta:

```
$query_exclusivo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE grupo = '$nombre' AND exclusivo = '1'");

        $exclusividad = mysqli_num_rows($query_exclusivo);

        <?php if ($exclusividad == 0) { ?>
                Tu codigo por si el grupo es gratuito.
            <?php } else if ($exclusividad >= 1) { ?>
            Tu codigo por si el grupo es exclusivo.
            <?php } ?>
```

Este codigo funciona a la perfeccion, si un usuario es gratuito y esta en un grupo exclusivo, no le cambia el atributo propio del usuario a "exclusivo" a menos que lo quieras, este solo cambia el atributo del equipo,.

Gracias a Mauricio Contreras por la idea.

Comment: No olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita por favor

Comment: Si, es dentro de 2 dias